# How to call function after everything is resolved?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, graphql, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to extract data from sites. My problem is with closing the browser after everything is fetched.

Please help me out :) This is a resolver function for GraphQL.

```
const Somesite = async ({ ticker }) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://Somesite.com/quote.ashx?t=' + ticker);
    let result = {
        ticker,
        market_cap: async () => {
            return await fetch_data_with_xpath(page, { ticker, xpath: "/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/b" })
        },
        float: async () => {
            return await fetch_data_with_xpath(page, { ticker, xpath: "/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[10]/b" })
        },
        insider_own: async () => {
            return await fetch_data_with_xpath(page, { ticker, xpath: "/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]/b" })
        },
        short_float: async () => {
            return await fetch_data_with_xpath(page, { ticker, xpath: "/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[10]/b" })
        },
        date: async () => {
            return moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY");
        },
        cash_per_share: async () => {
            return await fetch_data_with_xpath(page, { ticker, xpath: "/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/b" })
        },
        dept_equity: async () => {
            return await fetch_data_with_xpath(page, { ticker, xpath: "/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[4]/b/span" })
        },
        browser : async () => {
            return browser.close()
        }
    };


    return result;
};

const fetch_data_with_xpath = async (page, { ticker, xpath }) => {
    const element = await page.$x(xpath);
    let text = "";
    if (!!element) {
        text = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element[0]);
    }
    return text;
}
```

I've tried to open separate browser for each data element, well that is not very efficient and quickly hit the limit as well.

I can't leave the browser open, that is not an option. 
When I trigger the `browser.close` after defining the `result` browser closes prematurely and no data is fetched.

Answer (score 1):

First remove the `browser.close()` from inside your object, since the properties in objects are non-ordered, it's not going to work.

Assuming all elements on the object is a function, we can take advantage of `for..of` with `async..await`.

```
async function getResult() {
 // hold all of our related functions
 let resultFunctions = {
  ticker,
  market_cap: async () => {
   return fetch_data_with_xpath(page, {
    ticker,
    xpath: "/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/b"
   })
  }
 };

 let result = {}
 // run all functions inside the object
 for (let [key, fn] of Object.entries(resultFunctions)) {
  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
   result[key] = await fn()
  }

  // if it's not a function, 
  // then it's "Probably" a string according to our schema above
  if (typeof fn === 'string') result[key] = fn;
 }
 return result;
}

const result = await getResult()
await browser.close()
```